# Vaadin + LitElement - styles from `get styles()` not getting applied

Tags: css, vaadin, lit-element

I have a trivial LitElement class that I want to style with some internal CSS:

```
import {LitElement, html, css, customElement, property} from 'lit-element';


@customElement('address-card')
export class AddressCard extends LitElement {

  @property()
  streetAddress?: string;

  @property()
  postalCode?: string;

  @property()
  city?: string;


  static get styles() {
    return css`
      .address { border: 1px dashed gray; }
      `;
  }

  render() {
    return html`
    <div class="address">  
      <div>${this.streetAddress}</div> 
      <div>${this.postalCode} ${this.city}</div>
    </div>
    `;

  // Remove this method to render the contents of this view inside Shadow DOM
  createRenderRoot() {
    return this;
  }
}
```

The `static get styles()` method should allow me to add styles to the component, but nothing I add there seems to get applied. Not even a `* { ... }` selector, which should affect all elements, seems to do anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is the `createRenderRoot()` method. If you disable shadow root, there's no need to encapsulate styles inside the component implementation - you can use global CSS. If you want to encapsulate styles, remove the `createRenderRoot` override and the `static get styles()` rules will get applied.